# Kubernetes pod - Failed to determine the https port for redirect

Tags: azure, kubernetes

When i do kubectl logs pod_name -n namespace, i find this below:

```
warn: FileSystemXmlRepository[60]      Storing keys in a directory '/home/app/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
warn: XmlKeyManager[35]      No XML encryptor configured. Key {e4463e4a-d257-44ba-932e-494413eae8fd} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
warn: WarmupServicesStartupTask      Warming up 14 controllers on http://localhost:3000
fail: WarmupServicesStartupTask      Connection refused
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Connection refused
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (111): Connection refused
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at MCS.Core.Web.Api.WarmupServicesStartupTask.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<<StartAsync>b__2>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at MCS.Core.Web.Api.WarmupServicesStartupTask.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

> Hosting environment: lab Content root path: / Now listening on:
> http://[::]:3000 Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down. warn:
> HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]      Failed to determine the https port
> for redirect.

Can someone help me to find a solution?
Thanks a lot,
Mauro.

Comment: Have you tried, Storing encryption keys in a persistent location, such as a mounted volume or configuring an XML encryptor to encrypt data properly or Ensuring that the service being warmed up on localhost:3000 is running and accepting connections?

Comment: Did you ever get this issue resolved?